# How to test electron app using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, electron

In order to test an electron application. How does one use selenium to identify its elements or using F12 dev tools? As in order to write a selenium script one would have to identify the elements initially. How do I decompose an electron application to view its elements? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For this question, it depends on which webdriver Selenium is using. I am testing with Spectron based on Electron, but my elements are identified by `webdriver IO`.

To reach an element you can use the id, class, CSS or xPath

Next up I can get an [element](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/element.html) and do whatever I want with it

```java
browser.element(selector); // Default
browser.element('#id');
browser.element('.class');
browser.element('.multiple.classes.to.find.element');
browser.element('//xpath');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebdriverJS, then you need to run ./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver in this [step](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver/#start-chromedriver).

Comment: I already know this. In order to know what elements for automated testing when writing the script in either webdriver or selenium is what I am looking to find out.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

If that doesnt work read, ["How to make developer tools appear"](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-make-developer-tools-appear/16232).

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the documentation at https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver and I was able to capture the elements.